# How to remove special characters from start of string but leave in the body of the string?

Tags: c#

I have a very long string, I would like to remove keep only letters at the beginning:

Example: If the string starts like: *1234 I am going to the movies at 2pm: or !@#$% OMG I am 2 scared.*

Then output should be: ***I am going to the movies at 2pm:*** And OMG I am 2 scared.

Note: The 2 still preserved.

In a nutshell I only want to remove the special character at the beginning of the string but leave all else in. I could use a Regex like this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

But not sure how I would incorporate this with s `StartWith` method?

**By special character I am meaning only letters A-Z or a-z.**

Thanks

Comment: Your regex is good,  just put a `^` or `\A` at the start of it to anchor it to the beginning of the string. Edit: And a `+` or `*` at the end to remove all of those characters, not just the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(source, "^[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

^ at the beginning of regex pattern matches beginning of he string.

Comment: But what happens if the unwanted characters appear in the body of the string? Wont this replace it?

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: No. The leading `^` anchors it to the start of the string.

Comment: No, because there is ^ at the very beginning of the pattern.

Comment: You may consider stripping lead spaces as well.

Comment: Ahh, wow, that's pretty impressive. I was way off trying to use a `StartWith` method. This does the trick! Thanks everyone!!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Right...silly me. Space *is* a non-letter :-) My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This method of string may help: [String.TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you know the characters you want to remove.  Or if all the characters are together at the start you could also do

```
myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(' '));
```

to remove everything up until the first space